Why won't lazy.nvim update itself?
I'm trying to update to the latest lazy version for quite some time, but lazy refuses to and stays on the same version.


Please don’t post images of text. It would be helpful if you describe the sequence of actions you take and their results more precisely. Further, see https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604 for good ways to narrow down the problem.
